# How to get data from website using script?

Tags: php, json, curl

I would like to create a script which I can use for tracking prices from a travel website.

I don't see any problem with cutting the data from file ... but I don't know how to automate getting whole site with that information.

I've used the following call to get the website:

```
curl -o data.txt http://www.tui.pl/wypoczynek/kuba/varadero/iberostar-tainos-vra20116/OfferCodeWS/WAWVRA20171120113020171120201711301830L10VRA20116DZX1AA02
```

But the downloaded content doesn't contain the price as it is hidden:

```
<span class="price-group-desc">Cena za osobę:</span>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-5">
      {{^child}}
      <div class="old price">{{formattedAmount}} <sup class="currency">{{currencySymbol}}</sup></div>
      <div class="price">{{formattedDiscountAmount}} <sup class="currency">{{currencySymbol}}</sup></div>
      {{/child}}
    </div>
```

What to do ?

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to create your own robot to spider a website. For instance: The website can change, you might get blocked. Contact the owner of the site and ask them if they have a file you can download with the prices.

Comment: good point, but other way - there is a promotion, that if I will see that trip is cheaper than I have paided - they will give me back difference, so I need to view it everyday anyway - but I'll ask anyway

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the simple_html_dom library for php. I'm very satisfied with it as it's very easy to use (very much like JQuery for Javascript)
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

You could use it like this:

```
//getting the file    
$html = file_get_html('https://example.com/you/want/data/from');

//only selecting the element you want
$element = $html->find('.some_class');
```

So you can just take the values you want and use them to your wishes. I use a cron to automate the fetching of data.

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem, as value is not catched by the file_get_html